# Centering vertically and horzontally using translateX/Y not working as expected

Tags: css, centering

This: [vertical centering working great](http://jsfiddle.net/w9bvgc82/)
Code:

```
`   <div class="container">
        <h1>Vertical center with only 3 lines of code</h1>

        <section class="text">
            <p>I'm vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!</p>
        </section>
    </div>`
```

However if I try to center horizontally using the same approach via

```
left: 50%; translateX(-50%);
```

after uncommenting two lines in .container element in CSS
I get weird result: the container is centered horizontally, but vertical centering is lost.
What am I missing here, and how to achieve what I want: to center the container vertically and horizontally on the page via translateX/Y ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was because the latter property would overwrite the previous one. Thus, you would only see horizontal centering.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* This would be overwritten */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* By this.. */
}
```

The solution would be to combine the values like this:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

or..

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/oyyxpk1e/) - added vender prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

You're really close, change your CSS like this:

```
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: #59488b;
            padding: 1em;
            text-align:center;
        }
        * {
            text-align:center;
        }
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left:50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .text p {
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
        section {
            display: block;
            max-width: 500px;
            background: #433669;
            margin: 0 auto 1em;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: .5em;
            color: white;
            padding: 1em;
        }
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spb2har2/)

Comment: Thank you both Josh and Fabio! Both answers are correct.